# https authentication using Haskell

Tags: haskell, networking, web, https

I'm trying to write a haskell program that accesses a https url, where a file is automatically downloaded. The site requests authentication. 
I tried using the [Req](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/req) library but I couldn't understand all the web and networking concepts.

Can anyone give me some template code or at least to tell me more precisely where i can find the functions I need?

This is the code I wrote so far, but is'n not working:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Default.Class
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Data.Text as T
import GHC.Generics
import Network.HTTP.Req
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

main = runReq def $ do
    let myMethod = GET
        myUrl = https $ T.pack "https://..."
        myBody = NoReqBody
        myProxy = ignoreResponse
        myOption = basicAuth (B.pack "user") (B.pack "password")
    m <- req myMethod myUrl myBody myProxy myOption
    return ()
```

Comment: When you say "not working" you mean it's connecting fine but not passing the username and password?

Comment: I get a 'Name or service not known' message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sample example using the package `http-client`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack script --resolver lts-12.7
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L8
import           Network.HTTP.Client        (defaultManagerSettings, Manager, applyBasicAuth)
import           Network.HTTP.Simple
import Network.HTTP.Client.TLS (getGlobalManager)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    manager <- getGlobalManager

    printResponse manager "http://some-domain.com"


printResponse :: Manager -> Request -> IO ()    
printResponse mgr url = do
  let request = setRequestManager mgr url
      request' = applyBasicAuth "user" "password" request
  response <- httpLBS request'

  putStrLn $ "The status code was: " ++  show (getResponseStatusCode response)
  print $ getResponseHeader "Content-Type" response
  L8.putStrLn $ getResponseBody response
```

Some Reference documentation:

- https://haskell-lang.org/library/http-client
- https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.9/http-client-0.5.13.1/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:applyBasicAuth

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have another stupid question. How can I download "Network.HTTP.Simple" using cabal? The "cabal install Simple" seems to install another "Simple" library

Comment: @wasabi Network.HTTP.Simple is from the package http-conduit: https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.9/http-conduit-2.3.2/Network-HTTP-Simple.html

You can start by creating a cabal project and specifying the dependency of the package there. Another alternative (which I strongly recommend) is to use Stack: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/

A quick way of running haskell scripts is to use script interpreter feature: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#script-interpreter